# How to put Session data to textbox in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

I'm the newbie in Codeigniter. I put the textbox values to session and go to next page and when i click the back button on 2nd page, then the 1st page data should be still in textbox. How can I do that? Please help me.

Controller code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


public function index(){
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
public function page1(){

    $this->session->set_userdata('page1',$this->input->get());
    $this->config->load('config');
    $this->config->set_item('sess_expiration', '60');
    $this->load->view('pg2');
}
public function page2(){

    $this->session->set_userdata('page2',$this->input->get());
    $this->config->load('config');
    $this->config->set_item('sess_expiration', '60');
    $this->load->view('pg3');
}
public function page3(){
    $this->config->load('config');
    $this->config->set_item('sess_expiration', '60');
    $sess_data=$this->session->userdata();
    $ses_key = key($sess_data);
    if (empty($this->session->userdata("page1")))
    {   
        echo "Session has been Expired~!";
        $this->session->unset_userdata('page1');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('page2');
        //redirect(site_url(),'refresh');
    }
    else
    {
     $q1 = ($sess_data['page1']);
     $q2 = ($sess_data['page2']);

     $result1 = '';
     $result2 = '';
     $result3 = '';
     $result4 = '';

     $result5 = '';
     $result6 = '';
     $result7 = '';
     $result8 = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q1); $i++)
    {
        $key=key($q1);
        $val=$q1[$key];
        if ($val<> ' ')
        {
            if ($key === 'input1')
            {
                $result1 = $val;
                //echo $result1;
            }
            else if ($key === 'input2')
            {
                $result2 = $val;
                //echo $result2;
            }
            else if ($key === 'input3')
            {
                $result3 = $val;
                //echo $result3;
            }
            else
            {
                $result4 = $val;
                //echo $result4;
            }

           echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
        }
        next($q1);
    }


    for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q2); $i++)
    {
        $key=key($q2);
        $val=$q2[$key];
        if ($val<> ' ')
        {
            if ($key === 'input5')
            {
                $result5 = $val;
                //echo $result5;
            }
            else if ($key === 'input6')
            {
                $result6 = $val;
                //echo $result6;
            }
            else if ($key === 'input7')
            {
                $result7 = $val;
                //echo $result7;
            }
            else
            {
                $result8 = $val;
                //echo $result8;
            }

           echo " <br> <br> " . $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
        }
        next($q2);
    }

    //$this->testing_model->add_data('sess_table',['val'=>$result1,'val2'=>$result2]);
    $this->testing_model->add_data('user_table',['id'=>"default", 'text2'=>$result1, 'text3'=>$result2, 'text4'=>$result3, 'text5'=>$result4]);
    $this->testing_model->add_data('sess_table',['id'=>"default", 'val'=>$result5, 'val2'=>$result6, 'val3'=>$result7, 'val4'=>$result8]);

        echo "Successfully Saved to Database!";
        $this->session->unset_userdata('page1');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('page2');


    //$querydata=$this->testing_model->query('select * from sess_table');
    //print "<pre/>";
    // print_r($querydata);
    // foreach ($querydata as $key => $value) {
    //  print_r(json_decode($value->val,true));
    //  print_r(json_decode($value->val2,true));
    //  // echo json_decode($value->val.' ---- '.$value->val2;
    // }
    }
  }
}
```

View 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

</head>
<body>
page 1
<form method="get" action="<?= base_url('welcome/page1') ?>">
    input 1 <input name="input1" type="text"/> <br/>
    input 2 <input name="input2" type="text"/> <br/>
    input 3 <input name="input3" type="text"/> <br/>
    input 4 <input name="input4" type="text"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="go"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

View 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

</head>
<body>
page 2

<form method="get" action="<?= base_url('welcome/page2') ?>">
    input 1 <input name="input5" type="text" /> <br/>
    input 2 <input name="input6" type="text" /> <br/>
    input 3 <input name="input7" type="text" /> <br/>
    input 4 <input name="input8" type="text" /> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="go"/>
    <a type="button" href="<?= base_url('welcome/page2') ?>">Back</a>
</form>

</body>
```

View 3:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="<?= base_url('welcome/page3') ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
<a type="button" href="<?= base_url('welcome/page1') ?>">Back</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I put my code in own answer. Please help me.

Comment: you can edit you question @KyawZinWai

Answer (score 0):

Load library session in construct

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
}
```

Open your autoload.php in applications/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Answer (score 0):

The session data is the least of your problems.

First off, `$this->load->view('pg2');` does not call your other functions in your controller, it loads a view named 'pg2'. In your question you didn't show the names of your views but if 'View 1' is a file named pg1.php in the /views folder, your controller function could look like this:

```
public function pg1() {
        $this->session->set_userdata('page1',$this->input->get());
        $this->load->view('pg1');
}
```

And then you have to learn how to pass data to display in views too... Try to read up on the docs, for example here's the page on how views work: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html